# My website can post to Facebook Feed of a user although he is logged out from FB

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

On my page, users can upload pictures and post them to their facebook wall - but usually they should only be able to post on their wall if they are logged in into their facebook account. I check the user status with this piece of code:

```
// check if user is connected to facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                          'appId'  => Yii::app()->params['fbAppId'],
                          'secret' => Yii::app()->params['fbSecret'],
                        ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user = $facebook->getUser()) 
{
     try 
     {
         $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
         echo "you are logged in";
     } 
     catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
     {
         $user = NULL;
         echo "you are logged out";
     }
}
```

(And even that code, which is recommended to check if a user has not only a session but a valid fb login, returns true although I am no longer logged in at Fb.)

Now, if I log in to my own page via Facebook Connect, and then log out from FB - I am still logged in on my own webpage. Thats okay for the moment. But what shouldn't work is this piece of code:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

which means that the website will post the picture the user uploaded directly to a user's feed. And this seems to work although the user is logged out from facebook...

Btw, I request no offline permissons.

Best wishes,
Sebastian

Comment: where is your logout code?

Comment: In this scenario, the user only logs off from Facebook (by clicking logout on Facebook.com), but not from my site, which means he is still logged in on my webpage but has no valid Facebook login anymore. The logout routine of my website works, but doesn't play a role in this scenario.